# Explicit class instantiation for non-templated classes

Tags: c++, testing

In C++, you can explicitly instantiate a templated class like this:

```
template class A<B>;
```

This forces the compiler to include all of that class's methods its output, which is very useful for assessing which ones are covered by tests.

While (as I understand it) non-templated classes technically get instantiated automatically, unused methods of non-templated classes are often left out of the compiler's output (even with -O0 and other similar flags). Is there a way to force the compiler not to do that?

Comment: An exported or otherwise externally visible symbol can't be discarded. This isn't a language feature and depends on your compiler and platform. If you are compiling an executable directly, doing this is harder but I struggle to see why you would want to in that case.

Comment: I would like to do this because I'm trying to assess test coverage in a header-only library.

Comment: By "not to do that", you mean that you don't want the linker to discard uncalled class member functions?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want them to remain in the binary so that gcov can see they were there but not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of instantiation with non template classes. When the compiler encounters the definition of a member function, the definition is compiled right away.

Whether the function is outputted in the binary is up to the compiler and your setup. If you compile your program as a library, all functions will be implemented. If you use static linking, the linker won't add unused functions in you binary.

On the contrary, if you use dynamic linking, all exported definition will be there. Although non exported function such as function with static linkage can be inlined without having a separated definition.

Whether they are actually saved and outputted into the binary is something separated from the compilation itself. For example you could instantiate 100 template functions and in reality have none outputted in the binary. It's up to the linker if your function make it to the binary.

If your function is a public symbol, it will likely get into the binary.

Comment: I recognize that the definition is compiled right away, but I would like it to also compile the body of the methods and include that in the binary. Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "compile your program as a library"?

Comment: @seaotternerd yes, by "compiled right away" I meant the whole body (definition) of all the member functions are compiled.

Comment: @seaotternerd by compiling into a library I mean not compiling into an executable, but as a separated library.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to get a solution working with dynamic linking (the reason I write header-only libraries is that I hate linkers with a firey passion), but along the way I discovered some built-in compiler options in Clang that did what I want. I added the `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping` flags to my compilation, and then used llvm-profdata and llvm-cov to view the test coverage (as described [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html)).

Note for anyone else trying to make this work: make sure to use the same llvm version for all three of these commands (clang, llvm-profdata, and llvm-cov).